# Cannot start NFS in Centos 7: Failed to issue method call: No such file or directory

Tags: centos, nfs

I can't start an NFS server in CentOS7.

The packages downloaded:

```
yum -y install nfs-utils
yum -y install nfs-utils-lib
```

Enable/start services

```
systemctl enable/start rpcbind
systemctl enable/start nfs-server
systemctl enable/start nfs-lock
systemctl enable/start nfs-idmap
```

Which leads to :

```
systemctl enable nfs-lock
Failed to issue method call: No such file or directory
systemctl enable nfs-idmap
Failed to issue method call: No such file or directory
```

Created the share:

```
mkdir -p /test
chmod 777 /test
```

exported fine:

```
exportfs
/test           clientip/24
```

However, when performing `systemctl` restart `nfs-server`, it fails with dependency error, `journalctl` shows:

```
[user@server /]# journalctl -xn | grep failed
-- Subject: Unit proc-fs-nfsd.mount has failed
-- Unit proc-fs-nfsd.mount has failed.
-- The result is failed.
Jun 23 17:06:41 server systemd[1]: Dependency failed for NFS server and services.
-- Subject: Unit nfs-server.service has failed
-- Unit nfs-server.service has failed.
Jun 23 17:06:41 server systemd[1]: Dependency failed for NFS Mount Daemon.
-- Subject: Unit nfs-mountd.service has failed
-- Unit nfs-mountd.service has failed.
Jun 23 17:06:41 open
```

And the `systemctl` list-units status also show failure

```
systemctl list-units | grep nfs
proc-fs-nfsd.mount                      loaded failed failed    NFSD configuration filesystem
var-lib-nfs-rpc_pipefs.mount            loaded failed failed    RPC Pipe File System
nfs-config.service                      loaded active exited    Preprocess NFS configuration
nfs-idmapd.service                      loaded failed failed    NFSv4 ID-name mapping service
```

`/var/log/messages`:

```
Jun 23 17:06:41 server systemd: Dependency failed for RPC security service for NFS server.
Jun 23 17:06:41 server systemd: Dependency failed for RPC security service for NFS client and server.
Jun 23 17:06:41 server systemd: Unit var-lib-nfs-rpc_pipefs.mount entered failed state.
Jun 23 17:06:41 server systemd: nfs-idmapd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 23 17:06:41 server systemd: Unit nfs-idmapd.service entered failed state.
Jun 23 17:06:41 server systemd: proc-fs-nfsd.mount mount process exited, code=exited status=32
Jun 23 17:06:41 server systemd: Dependency failed for NFS server and services.
Jun 23 17:06:41 server systemd: Dependency failed for NFS Mount Daemon.
Jun 23 17:06:41 server systemd: Unit proc-fs-nfsd.mount entered failed state.
Jun 23 17:12:53 server mount: mount: unknown filesystem type 'nfsd'
Jun 23 17:12:53 server systemd: proc-fs-nfsd.mount mount process exited, code=exited status=32
Jun 23 17:12:53 server rpc.idmapd[842]: main: open(/var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs//nfs): No such file or directory
Jun 23 17:12:53 server systemd: Dependency failed for NFS server and services.
Jun 23 17:12:53 server systemd: Dependency failed for NFSv4 ID-name mapping service.
Jun 23 17:12:53 server systemd: Dependency failed for NFS Mount Daemon.
Jun 23 17:12:53 server systemd: Unit proc-fs-nfsd.mount entered failed state.
```

The client reports, and  I assume it's normal as per the errors above:

```
RPC: Remote system errorRPC: Port mapper failure - RPC: Timed out.
```

Comment: Found what may be the root cause. Server is a part of an openvz environment, and is running "stab" kernel: 
Linux version 2.6.32-042stab106.4

Someone with more experience to confirm it, but I believe that is the issue: this kernel/environment has limited NFS functionality.

Comment: May be an issue with systemd as well; see: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1159308

Comment: This solved my issue
https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=53896 Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem with @user136564 's post.

> This solved my issue https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=53896

I found my problem was rpcbind won't start on boot even though I enabled it in systemd and I could start it manually.

### These commands are what I did on CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)

#### Install nfs-utils

```
yum install -y nfs-utils
```

#### Append text to `/etc/fstab`

```
192.168.1.100:/mnt/nfs-server /mnt/nfs-client nfs defaults,nofail,x-systemd.automount 0 0
```

Some articles said `noauto,x-systemd.automount` is better, but it worked without `noauto` for me.

#### Check whether mount works

```
systemctl start rpcbind
systemctl enable rpcbind
mount -a
```

#### Fix the problem CentOS 7 won't auto-mount NFS on boot

Append text to the end of /usr/lib/systemd/system/nfs-idmap.service

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Append text to the end of /usr/lib/systemd/system/nfs-lock.service

```
[Install]
WantedBy=nfs.target
```

#### Enable related services

```
systemctl enable nfs-idmapd.service 
systemctl enable rpc-statd.service 

systemctl enable rpcbind.socket

systemctl status nfs-idmapd.service -l
systemctl status rpc-statd.service –l
```

#### Then restarted the OS, I got it.

```
shutdown -r now
```

Comment: You just saved my life.